# How to query strings in mongodb without being case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using mongodb in javascript and I was wondering how to effectively query names in a collection. As it is, I have 2 fields for my collections for the same thing which is pretty reduntent.

`queryName: String`
and  `name: String`

The reason I do this is because if I have the name "John" for name, and I try try query the collection for the name "john"(note how the j is lowercase). It will return null. That's why I have the field queryName that takes the name and puts it into a format that's searchable. I was wondering if there's an option to disable case sensitivity and getting rid of spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex):

```
db.collection.find({name: /^john$/i });
```

Not sure what you mean when explaining why you have `queryName` and `name`, unless the former is some sort of normalization of the `name` field.

If you want to get rid of spaces, you'll have to be more specific. Spaces surrounding the query? Spaces in-between characters? You can do either with regex, though the latter is more cumbersome. A common practice is to `trim()` your data before you store it, though, so you don't have this problem.

```
db.collection.find({name: /^\s*john\s*$/i });
```

I'll leave it to OP to modify use for more complicated white space handling.

Comment: Thank you this was actually really helpful. I didn't know you can use regex to query mongodb database

Comment: How would one use this example if john was a variable?